# Time slots are not appearing in full calendar components

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

Iam working on full calendar version v3.2.0.But In week and time view,Time slots are not appearing in left hand column

[image]

I have tried following Code in calendar:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {

                left: 'today prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'

            },
            contentHeight:'auto',       //auto
            slotDuration: '00:15:00',
            slotLabelInterval: 15,
            slotLabelFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
            defaultDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            navLinks:true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            weekends: component.get('v.weekends'),
            eventBackgroundColor: component.get('v.eventBackgroundColor'),
            eventBorderColor: component.get('v.eventBorderColor'),
            eventTextColor: component.get('v.eventTextColor'),
            events: eventArray,
```